# fish shell and global npm modules

Tags: npm, fish

I'm experiencing some issues with my local environment.

**I'm using:**

- homebrew (1.1.4)
- fish shell (2.4)
- n version manager (2.1.0)
- node
- npm

All of the above were initially installed via homebrew.

**Issues:**

- Any globally installed modules cannot be run.
- I cannot update npm versions.

The node versions I use regularly are 0.10.48 and 6.9.2 - but mostly 4.6.2.

I've created some aliases in fish to be able to get the the global modules to run. I'd prefer to address the root cause rather than continue applying further bandaids though.

**Extra info:**

```
~> npm config get prefix
/Users/me/.npm-packages

~> npm bin
/Users/me/node_modules/.bin
```

What happens when I try to update npm:

```
~> npm install -g npm@3
/Users/me/.npm-packages/bin/npm -> /Users/me/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@3.10.10 /Users/me/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm
~> npm -v
2.15.9
```

When I try to call a global module:

```
~> gulp
fish: Unknown command 'gulp'
```

What I've tried in order to fix the global modules:

```
~> cat ~/.config/fish/config.fish
set fish_user_paths /Users/me/.npm-packages

ls ~/.config/fish/functions
bower.fish ember.fish pm2.fish

~> cat ~/.config/fish/functions/bower.fish 
function bower
    /Users/me/.npm-packages/bin/bower  $argv;
end
```

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated! I've been trying to fix this for awhile now without any luck!

Comment: This looks like a simple case of `/Users/me/.npm-packages/bin/` not being in `PATH`. Does `echo $PATH` include `/Users/me/.npm-packages/bin/`?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've just checked and it appears to be there:

Comment: Does `echo $PATH` show any colons? (It shouldn't, it should look space-delimited) If no colons, then `gulp` must be somewhere else. What does `which gulp` show, when run from an environment where gulp works?

Comment: Thanks again for replying.

`echo $PATH ~> /Users/me/.npm-packages /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin`

I tried `which gulp` (and other modules) and it just returns nothing. I tried both in fish shell and bash.

Comment: Hmm, what does `type gulp` show in bash then?

Comment: `bash: type: gulp: not found`

Comment: I have a very similar setup, and find myself having to run `nvm use default` for every new shell, see also https://github.com/fisherman/nvm/issues/11

Comment: For anyone reading this, I don't believe my issue is specifically related to fish shell anymore, as I've tested bash and zsh and experience the same issue.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I resolved this by completely uninstalling (and deleting any traces of) `node`, `npm` and `n`, uninstalling `fish` shell and changing to `zsh` instead.

Afterwards, I installed `nvm` and used it to restore `node` on my machine.

Global npm modules now work.

Answer (score 6):

You can use installed npm modules. You just need to add npm global path to the shell. To do that, I ran:

```
$ npm config get prefix
// Output: /usr/local/Cellar/node/9.2.1
```

and then, added to my `fish/config.fish`:

```
set PATH /usr/local/Cellar/node/9.2.1/bin $PATH
```

This is the [Github related link](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3023) that helped me solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For me non of this worked, so i installed oh my fish nvm [plugin](https://github.com/derekstavis/plugin-nvm)

```
omf install nvm
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you install node application globally https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Configuring in OSX 10.12.5 with
fish v2.6.0
node v8.1.0
example command in terminal returns both

```
term~> npm install jshint -g
/Users/username/npm-global/lib/node_modules/bin/jshint -> 
/Users/username/npm-global/lib/node_modules/jshint/bin/jshint
```

the PATH you should have in shell to enable you to execute *jshint* (*installed package*) -> pointing to the actual install location

Include line below for configuring PATH in file ~/.profile

```
export PATH="$HOME/npm-global/lib/node-modules/:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

My permanent solution (with macOS Mojave and fish 2.7.1):

```
set -U fish_user_paths /Users/{USERNAME}/.npm-packages/bin $fish_user_paths
```

Btw, below one works but only in terminal session:

```
set PATH $PATH /Users/{USERNAME}/.npm-packages/bin
```

Note: You can find npm-packages path with:

```
printf "%s\n" $PATH
```

Comment: or `fish_add_path /Users/{USERNAME}/.npm-packages/bin   `